# Properly mount a windows share to move files on the mountpoint

Tags: debian, mount, performance, cifs, move

This question resulted from a question of mine on [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757374/improve-performance-of-moving-a-growing-large-number-of-files-in-a-mounted-fold).

I mount a windows share with `mount -t cifs -o username=username,password=password,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //192.168.1.120/storage /mnt/storage`, then have scripts operate on the mountpoint on a debian machine.

The mountpoint `/mnt/storage` will contain a very rapidly growing number of files which are moved to a subdirectory in batches, where they are processed.

My problem is that the moving is relatively slow and I fear that this is because I'm unable to just alter the filetable (simply change the information where the file is on the hdd).

I'm currently using `shutil.move(src,dst)` in python, but also considered using `os.rename(src,dst)` or a subprocess using `mv`.

Is my fear correct - if so is there a way to *mount more efficiently*?

**edit**: I just went over the documentation of `shutil.move()` again and read this:

```
If the destination is on the current filesystem, then os.rename() is used.
Otherwise, src is copied (using shutil.copy2()) to dst and then removed.
```

This sounds like it could be an issue, if it is not *"on the current filesystem"*, how do I know if I am *"on the current filesystem"*

**edit2**: In case someone's interested in what I found out, I'll copy&paste me edit from stackoverflow here as well..

I wrote a script to test the speed differences between the various methods of moving.
First created 1x5GB (`dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/storage/source/test.file bs=100M count=50`), then with 100x5MB (`for i in {1..100}; do dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/storage/source/file$i bs=1M count=5`) and finally with 10000x5kB (`for i in {1..100000}; do dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/storage/source/file$i bs=1k count=5`)

```
from shutil import move
from os import rename
from datetime import datetime
import subprocess
import os

print("Subprocess mv: for every file in directory..")
s = datetime.now()
for f in os.listdir("/mnt/storage/source/"):
    try:
        subprocess.call(["mv /mnt/storage/source/"+str(f)+" /mnt/storage/mv"],shell=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
e = datetime.now()
print("took {}".format(e-s)+"\n")

print("Subprocessmv : directory/*..")
s = datetime.now()
try:
    subprocess.call(["mv /mnt/storage/mv/* /mnt/storage/mvf"],shell=True)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
e = datetime.now()
print("took {}".format(e-s)+"\n")


print("shutil.move: for every file file in directory..")
s = datetime.now()
for f in os.listdir("/mnt/storage/mvf/"):
    try:    
        move("/mnt/storage/mvf/"+str(f),"/mnt/storage/move")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
e = datetime.now()
print("took {}".format(e-s)+"\n")

print("os.rename: for every file in directory..")
s = datetime.now()
for f in os.listdir("/mnt/storage/move/"):
    try:
        rename("/mnt/storage/move/"+str(f),"/mnt/storage/rename/"+str(f))
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
e = datetime.now()
print("took {}".format(e-s)+"\n")


if os.path.isdir("/mnt/storage/rename_new"):
    rmtree('/mnt/storage/rename_new')
print("os.rename & os.mkdir: rename source dir to destination & make new source dir..")
s = datetime.now()
rename("/mnt/storage/rename/","/mnt/storage/rename_new")
os.mkdir("/mnt/storage/rename/")
e = datetime.now()
print("took {}".format(e-s)+"\n")
```

Which revealed that there's not that much of a difference.. The 5GB file was moved really fast, which tells me that the moving, by altering the file table works. Here are the results of the 10000*5kB files (It felt like the results depend on the current network workload. e.g. the first `mv` test took 2m 28s, than later with the same files 3m 22s, also was `os.rename()` the fastest method most of the times..):

```
Subprocess mv: for every file in directory..
took 0:02:47.665174

Subprocessmv : directory/*..
took 0:01:40.087872

shutil.move: for every file file in directory..
took 0:01:48.454184

os.rename: for every file in directory..
rename took 0:02:05.597933

os.rename & os.mkdir: rename source dir to destination & make new source dir..
took 0:00:00.005704
```